# How publish content on multiple websites of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have multiple wordpress websites, i want to control their content from one website, i want to add/publish content on one wordpress website and it should publish on all websites, please let me know how it is possible ? 
is this some type of "Wordpress Network" ?
one guy suggested me to use linksalpha, but i can not find wordpress content publishing on that platform, please guide me how to do that.
thank you very much.